# SQL Server trigger case statement NOT catching

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a trigger that when the SAMPLE table column is updated, it uses a case statement to update a column in another table. Currently the trigger does not catch any of the `WHEN` clauses. The value in the `ELSE` clause is what is used to do the update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SAMPVAL
ON dbo.SAMPLE
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE U
    SET U.VALIDATED = CASE
                         WHEN (U.VALIDATED IS NULL AND LEN(INSERTED.VALUSER) > 0)  
                            THEN 'VAL1'
                         WHEN (LEN(U.VALIDATED) > 0 AND U.VALIDATED = 'VAL1') 
                            THEN 'VAL2'
                         WHEN (LEN(U.VALIDATED) = 0) 
                            THEN 'NEWERVAL'
                         WHEN (LEN(U.VALIDATED) > 0) 
                            THEN 'NEWERVAL1'
                         ELSE '-'
                      END
    FROM INSERTED 
    INNER JOIN SUSERFLDS U ON U.SAMPNO = INSERTED.SAMPNO
END;
```

If the `U.VALIDATED` field is empty and `SAMPLE.VALUSER` column length is greater than zero, then the `SUSERFLDS.VALIDATED = 'VAL1'`. When I test this, the `SUSERFLDS.VALIDATED` column gets updated to "-".

Comment: Just to be clear, does your statement `If the U.VALIDATED field is empty` mean null or empty, such as an empty string?

Comment: Some example test data would be helpful - ideally in the form of DDL+DML statements.

Comment: @TomC either, but typically I used a LEN to determine if the field is empty. But by default that field is NULL.

Comment: My test worked as expected... so sample data required.

Comment: `len(null)` is null, so that check won't work if null.

Comment: @TomC  I got it figured out. The ELSE '-' is what was causing the issue. When I validate through the front end, the application updates the table TWICE. So what I was in fact seeing was the result of the trigger firing off twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SAMPVAL
ON dbo.SAMPLE
FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
  UPDATE U
    SET U.VALIDATED = CASE
    WHEN (U.VALIDATED IS NULL AND LEN(INSERTED.VALUSER) > 0) THEN 'VAL1'
    WHEN (LEN(U.VALIDATED) > 0 AND U.VALIDATED = 'VAL1') THEN 'VAL2'
    WHEN (LEN(U.VALIDATED) = 0) THEN 'NEWERVAL'
    WHEN (LEN(U.VALIDATED) > 0) THEN 'NEWERVAL1'
    ELSE U.VALIDATED
    END
  FROM INSERTED 
  INNER JOIN SUSERFLDS U ON U.SAMPNO =INSERTED.SAMPNO
END;
```

Changing `ELSE '-'` to `ELSE U.VALIDATED` fixed the issue.